# Replace thumb size in src

Tags: javascript, replacewith

I have this code :

```
<div class="track">
<a href="#" rel="loadpage"><img src="http://localhost/thumb.php?src=2015381915_1861178087_859395037.jpg&amp;t=m&amp;w=112&amp;h=112" alt="alt"></a
</div>
```

So, i want to change "112&h=112" size with js.
Thanks for any advice!

Comment: And you've tried to do... what, exactly?

Comment: Yes! I tried many Js simple, but not work !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this code work for me !

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload=function(){
        $("img").each(function(){
            var src=$(this).attr("src");
          src=src.replace("112&h=112","200&h=200");
          var src=$(this).attr("src",src);
        });
        }
</script>
```